# gradle dependency can't be resolved

Tags: android, gradle

I included some dependencies to my android app. This works perfectly on my own computer. However if I try to build this on my company computer it will cause an error that he coulnd't resolve the dependency. I assume this is due to the proxy server. I tried to configure it for gradle with adding this to the gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.proxySet=true
systemProp.http.proxyHost=[proxy]
systemProp.http.proxyPort=[port]
systemProp.http.proxyUser=[username]
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=[password]
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain

systemProp.https.proxyHost=[proxy]
systemProp.https.proxyPort=[port]
systemProp.https.proxyUser=[username]
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=[password]
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
```

This works for all except for com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.5.1. If I remove this dependency the builds works perfectly and all other dependency are fetched.

The developer states on the github page that you shall add this repo if you having issues: maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }

So for now I have this repositories added:

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
  maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }
  mavenLocal()
}
```

But it still gets the same error.

I assume that gradle tries to get this package via https and having some problems with it. Does anyone have an idea what I missconfigured and how I can fix this?

Thanks
NPadrutt

Comment: try putting mavenLocal()

Comment: thanks for your answer. but seems not to work aswell. I tried it with just adding it or replacing the current maven repo with the mavenlocal. bot caused the same error.

Comment: put it above the maven or just below the jcenter

Comment: unfortunately the same.